# How to return the maximum value of an array list for a deck of playing cards?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, compare

I am trying to develop a card game as shown:

> - In the beginning of the game, each player takes turn to draw a card from a shuffled deck of 52 cards. The players should have the same number of cards.
> - For example, if there are 5 players, then each player will get 10 cards. The game then proceeds in rounds.
> - In each round, each player plays a card. The player who plays the largest card wins. The order of the cards that a player plays is the order of getting the card.
> - For example, if Alice draws S5, D2, HK, SA, C4 in this order, she will play S5 in the first round, D2 in the second round, and so on.

**Issue**: In class *CardGame*, I'm having issues with the *play()* method. In the *//develop the loop for each round* part, my approach is to create 2 array lists and ultimately print out the name of the winner of the round:

- *compare1* array list to store the played cards
- *compare2* array list to store the compared cards from the *compare* array list

However, the error I'm getting is:

```
Alice has cards: [S2, DJ, D8, D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [S10, S7, S4, DK, D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [H5, H2, SQ, S9, S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [HK, H10, H7, H4, SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [C8, C5, C2, HQ, H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [D3, CK, C10, C7, C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays S2
Bob plays S10
Cathy plays H5
David plays HK
Emily plays C8
Fred plays D3
The winner of this round is Alice
The winner of this round is Bob
The winner of this round is David
Alice has cards: [D8, D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [S4, DK, D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [SQ, S9, S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [H7, H4, SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [C2, HQ, H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [C10, C7, C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays D8
Bob plays S4
Cathy plays SQ
David plays H7
Emily plays C2
Fred plays C10
The winner of this round is Alice
The winner of this round is Bob
The winner of this round is David
The winner of this round is Fred
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 6
    at CardGame.play(CardGame.java:52)
    at CardGameDriver.main(CardGameDriver.java:8)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the expected program output**:

```
Alice has cards: [S2, DJ, D8, D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [S10, S7, S4, DK, D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [H5, H2, SQ, S9, S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [HK, H10, H7, H4, SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [C8, C5, C2, HQ, H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [D3, CK, C10, C7, C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays S2
Bob plays S10
Cathy plays H5
David plays HK
Emily plays C8
Fred plays D3
The winner of this round is David.

Alice has cards: [DJ, D8, D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [S7, S4, DK, D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [H2, SQ, S9, S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [H10, H7, H4, SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [C5, C2, HQ, H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [CK, C10, C7, C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays DJ
Bob plays S7
Cathy plays H2
David plays H10
Emily plays C5
Fred plays CK
The winner of this round is Fred.

Alice has cards: [D8, D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [S4, DK, D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [SQ, S9, S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [H7, H4, SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [C2, HQ, H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [C10, C7, C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays D8
Bob plays S4
Cathy plays SQ
David plays H7
Emily plays C2
Fred plays C10
The winner of this round is Cathy.

Alice has cards: [D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [DK, D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [S9, S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [H4, SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [HQ, H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [C7, C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays D5
Bob plays DK
Cathy plays S9
David plays H4
Emily plays HQ
Fred plays C7
The winner of this round is Bob.

Alice has cards: [D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [D10, D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [S6, S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [SA, SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [H9, H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [C4, HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays D2
Bob plays D10
Cathy plays S6
David plays SA
Emily plays H9
Fred plays C4
The winner of this round is David.

Alice has cards: [CQ, C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [D7, D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [S3, DQ, D9]
David has cards: [SJ, S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [H6, H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [HA, HJ, H8]
Alice plays CQ
Bob plays D7
Cathy plays S3
David plays SJ
Emily plays H6
Fred plays HA
The winner of this round is Fred.

Alice has cards: [C9, C6]
Bob has cards: [D4, CA]
Cathy has cards: [DQ, D9]
David has cards: [S8, S5]
Emily has cards: [H3, SK]
Fred has cards: [HJ, H8]
Alice plays C9
Bob plays D4
Cathy plays DQ
David plays S8
Emily plays H3
Fred plays HJ
The winner of this round is Cathy.

Alice has cards: [C6]
Bob has cards: [CA]
Cathy has cards: [D9]
David has cards: [S5]
Emily has cards: [SK]
Fred has cards: [H8]
Alice plays C6
Bob plays CA
Cathy plays D9
David plays S5
Emily plays SK
Fred plays H8
The winner of this round is Bob.
```

**Here are my codes**:

```
// YOU CANNOT MODIFY THIS FILE
public class CardGameDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Player[] players = InitializePlayer.getPlayers();
    CardGame game = new CardGame(players);
    game.play();
  }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardGame {

  // YOU CANNOT DEFINE OTHER INSTANCE VARIABLES
  private Player[] players; // players in this game
  private int numRounds;    // number of rounds in this game
  private Deck deck;        // deck of cards

  // constructor
  // YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD
  public CardGame(Player[] players) {

    this.players = players;
    deck = new Deck(5);

  }

  // implement this method
  public void play() {

    // find out the number of rounds in this game
      numRounds = 52/players.length;

    // distribute cards among players
      for (int x=0; x<numRounds; x++) {
          for (int y=0; y<players.length; y++) {
              players[y].addCard(Deck.drawCard());
          }
      }


    // develop the loop for each round
    // (1) print out the cards each player has
    // (2) print out the cards each player plays
    // (3) identify the winner of this round
      ArrayList<Card> compare1 = new ArrayList<Card>();
      ArrayList<Card> compare2 = new ArrayList<Card>();


      for (int i=0; i<numRounds; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<players.length; j++) {
              players[j].printHand();
          }
          for (int k=0; k<players.length; k++) {
              System.out.print(players[k].getName() + " plays" + " ");
              System.out.println(players[k].playCard());
              compare1.add(players[k].playCard());
          }
          for (int l=0; l<compare1.size()-1; l++) {
              if (compare1.get(l).compareTo(compare1.get(l+1)) == 1) {
                System.out.println("The winner of this round is " + players[l].getName());
              }
          }
      }
  }

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player {

  // NO MORE INSTANCE VARIABLE CAN BE DEFINED
  private String name;  // name of the player
  private ArrayList<Card> cards; // cards the player has

  // YOU CANNOT MODIFY THIS FUNCTION
  public Player(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  }

  // YOU CANNOT MODIFY THIS FUNCTION
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  // implement this method
  void addCard(Card card) {
        cards.add(card);
  }

  // implement this method
  public Card playCard() {
        Card removed = cards.remove(0);
        return removed;
  }

  // YOU CANNOT MODIFY THIS FUNCTION
  public void printHand() {
    System.out.print(name);
    System.out.println(" has cards: " + cards);
  }
}
```

```
public class Card {
    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    public Card (Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return suit + "" + rank;
    }

    public int compareTo(Card c) {
        int diffRank = rank.ordinal() - c.rank.ordinal();
        if (diffRank < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (diffRank > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (diffRank == 0) {
            int diffSuit = suit.ordinal() - c.suit.ordinal();
            if (diffSuit < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (diffSuit > 0) {
                return 1;
            } 
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
// YOU CANNOT MODIFY THIS FILE
public class InitializePlayer {

  public static Player[] getPlayers() {
    Player players[] = new Player[6];

    players[0] = new Player("Alice");
    players[1] = new Player("Bob");
    players[2] = new Player("Cathy");
    players[3] = new Player("David");
    players[4] = new Player("Emily");
    players[5] = new Player("Fred");

    return players;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that you didn't take the time to read the [mre] link as previously requested, that you've instead posted a ton of code, most of it unrelated to the problem at hand, making it more difficult to answer your question

Comment: The best way to debug index out of bounds exception is to run your code through your debugger, seeing where and why the exception occurs.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the link. I edited post and deleted old one.

Answer (score 3):

The stacktrace shows that the problem was triggered by a call to `ArrayList.get` in your `play()` method.  There is only one place where that happens:

```
for (int l = 0; l < compare1.size(); l++) {
    if (compare1.get(l).compareTo(compare1.get(l + 1)) == 1) {
        System.out.println("The winner of this round is " + players[l].getName());
    }
}
```

If a list has size `S`, it has elements at positions `0` to `S - 1`

Your `l` goes from `0` to `S - 1`.  But you are comparing the element at `l` with the element at `l + 1`.  `l + 1` goes up to `S` and therefore `get(S)` is attempting to get an element with an index that is out of range.

Hence the exception.

Solution:

```
for (int l = 0; l < compare1.size() - 1; l++) {
    if (compare1.get(l).compareTo(compare1.get(l + 1)) == 1) {
        System.out.println("The winner of this round is " + players[l].getName());
    }
}
```

As you can see, all that is required is reading the stacktrace to work out where the problem occurred ... and a bit of logic.

A debugger would have been another way to find the location of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I made the changes but got this for the output:

`Alice has cards: [S2, DJ, D8, D5, D2, CQ, C9, C6]
Player@2ff4acd0 playsS2
Player@54bedef2 playsS10
The winner of this round is Alice
Player@5caf905d playsH5
The winner of this round is Alice
The winner of this round is Bob`



And it keeps going until I get this error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 6
 at CardGame.play(CardGame.java:49)
 at CardGameDriver.main(CardGameDriver.java:8)`

Comment: So now you have encountered a different bug.  Have you tried following the approach that I used in finding the first one?  1) Read stacktrace to find where the problem occurred.  2) Read code and apply simple logic to work out how / why the index is out of bounds.  3) If necessary, use debugger to get extra information.  (Hint: you are the person who needs to learn how to find bugs ... not me.)